# Prove $2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2 + 1} = \frac{\pi}{4}\mathrm{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2})$$

I tried to consider breaking up the alternating factor of the series by decomposing it into 2 separate series - one adding the even terms and the other subtracting the odd terms, but then I couldn’t figure out where to go.
My attempt, letting $S$ be the sum of interest.

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2(2k)+1)}{(2(2k)+1)^2 + 1} -   \frac{(2(2k+1)+1)}{(2(2k+1)+1)^2 + 1}$$

Don’t know what else to do.

Comment: [See this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275759/solve-int-limits-0-infty-frac-cosx-coshx-dx-without-complex-in/1275877#1275877) -- (lines 3-9 of RobJohn's answer for example).

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3293301/721644).

Comment: Awesome, thank you.