# How to compute this series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{a^2+(z+2n\pi)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, mittag-leffler-function

How to compute this series

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{a^2+(z+2n\pi)^2}~~~~~~~a, z\in\mathbb R$$

Wolfram gives the following result:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{a^2+(z+2n\pi)^2}=\frac1{4a}\coth\frac{a-iz}{2}+\frac1{4a}\coth\frac{a+iz}{2}+\frac1{2a}\lfloor \frac{\arg(z+ia)}{2\pi}\rfloor$$

I know how to compute the series

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{a^2+(2n\pi)^2}$$

which is the Mittag-Leffler's series. But for this problem, there is a shift $(z+2n\pi)$, and how to deal with this? Another question is about the term

$$\frac1{2a}\lfloor \frac{\arg(z+ia)}{2\pi}\rfloor$$

which is appearing in Wolfram's output. I don't know why there is this term, especially, if both $z$ and $a$ are real. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Let $f(u)=1/[a^2+(2u\pi+z)^2]$ and choose a proper contour to integrate $f(u)\cot(\pi u)$.

Comment: I suppose that this comes from a partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608059/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1zn2a2?noredirect=1