# Summation of the series$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Evaluate the sum of the following series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+4}$$

I saw a video in youtube where it is solved using complex analysis. What other method can be used to solve this?

Comment: Hi Kalpan; Can you post the link?

Comment: One can use the [Poisson summation formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/386759/73025).

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=99Tnu0-0S9g

Comment: Hi @O.L.Thanks! The problem is solved in the video more or less similar to your answer. In fact , it is done almost the same way as in the 2nd answer in the link you mentioned.

Comment: Have you tried to use fourier analysis ? One can calculate the sum of the $\frac{1}{n^2}$ using a suitable function, here the term is different but I think it's worth looking into it..

Comment: If you are familiar with Euler's approach to the [Basel problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), differentiate the natural logarithm of his infinite product formula for the sine function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{a^2+n^2}=\frac{1+a\pi\coth a\pi}{2a^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208317/show-sum-n-0-infty-frac1a2n2-frac1a-pi-coth-a-pi2a2)

Answer (score 1):

A proof from scratch. We may notice that
$$ \frac{1}{n^2+4}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} e^{-2x}\,dx $$
by integration by parts, so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+4} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}W(x) e^{-2x}\,dx $$
with $W(x)$ being the $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function which equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on $(0,2\pi)$.
 This Fourier series allows to state
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+4} = \left(1+e^{-2\pi}+e^{-4\pi}+\ldots\right)\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\pi-x}{2}e^{-2x}\,dx $$
and ultimately
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+4} = \frac{1}{1-e^{-2\pi}}\left[\frac{1}{8}e^{-2x}(1-2\pi+2x)\right]_{0}^{2\pi}=\frac{2\pi\coth(2\pi)-1}{8}. $$

Answer (score 0):

After asking the same question to my prof, he get's this:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+4}=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(2\pi coth(2\pi )-1\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(2\pi \left(1+\frac{2}{-1+e^{4\pi}}\right)-1\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(2\pi +\frac{4\pi}{e^{4\pi}-1}-1\right)=$$
$$\frac{1+2\pi +2\pi e^{4\pi}-e^{4\pi}}{8e^{4\pi}-8}$$