# Show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+3n+1}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{5}}{5}\tan\frac{\pi\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

How to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+3n+1}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{5}}{5}\tan\frac{\pi\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
?

**My try:**

We have
$$n+3n+1=\left(n+\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\left(n+\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right),$$
so
$$\frac{1}{n^2+3n+1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1}{2n+3-\sqrt{5}}-\frac{1}{2n+3+\sqrt{5}}\right).$$
Then, I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What makes you the greatest difficulty in this task? Which way went your transformations?

Comment: This answer should be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112161 .

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386667).

Answer (score 8):

I think we can make some use of the residue theorem. Write $n^2+3 n+1 = (n+3/2)^2-5/4$ and the sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{\left (n+\frac{3}{2} \right )^2-\frac{5}{4}} = \frac12 \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac1{\left (n+\frac{3}{2} \right )^2-\frac{5}{4}} - 1 +1$$

(To get the doubly infinite sum, I had to add back the $n=0$ and $n=-1$ terms, which happen to sum to zero.)

The sum on the RHS may be attacked via the residue theorem, using the following:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = - \pi \sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} [f(z)\cot{\pi z} ] $$

where $z_k$ is a non-integer pole of $f$.  The poles are at

$$z_{\pm} = -\frac{3}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} $$

The sum is then equal to

$$\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{5}} \left [\cot{\left (\frac{3 \pi}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5} \pi}{2} \right )} - \cot{\left (\frac{3 \pi}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5} \pi}{2} \right )} \right ] = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}\tan{\frac{\sqrt{5}\pi}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$ n^2+3n+1=(n+\frac{3}{2})^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt 5i}{2}\right)^2 $$
and
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+3n+1}&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+\frac{3}{2})^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt 5i}{2}\right)^2}\\
&=&\frac12\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{(n+\frac{3}{2})^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt 5i}{2}\right)^2}.
\end{eqnarray}
Then using the result from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386667/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n-a2b2), you will get the answer.