# Show $\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2\ln x }{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)}}dx=\frac{-π^2}{16(2+\sqrt{2})}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Question:

> Prove that $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)}}dx=\frac{-π^2}{16(2+\sqrt{2})}$$

Using partial fraction,we get

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)}}dx\\
= &\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1+x}dx+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x^2-1)\ln x}{1+x^4}dx
\end{align}

I got first integral as 
$\frac{-\pi^2}{6}$ and second integral as $\frac{-\pi^2}{12}$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^2\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)}}dx=\frac{-\pi^2}{16}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x^2-1)\ln x}{1+x^4}dx$$

I got stuck with third integral, which seems difficult to evaluate.
${}{}{}$
A note is also written saying that:-
The reader should evaluate the family of integrals  ${I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac {x^{2n}\ln x}{{(1-x^2)}{(1+x^4)^n}}dx{,n} \in N}$
The computation of the first few special values indicates an interesting arithmetic structure of the answer.

How to evaluate integral for $n$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067499/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracx2-1-lnx1x4dx/1067548#1067548) for three different ways to evaluate the third integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the third integral as

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(x^2-1)\ln x}{1+x^4}dx 
= -\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^4}dx
$$

Use the general result

$$J(a)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^m}dx=\frac{\pi}m\csc\frac{\pi a}m
$$

and let $m=4$ to obtain
$$I= - J’(1)= \frac{\pi^2}{8\sqrt2} $$

Comment: What substitution did you perform in your "rewrite the third integral as" step? Perhaps I'm missing something, but this rewriting does not seem trivially obvious.

Comment: How to do ${I_{n}}$

Comment: @LtSten substitute $x=1/t$

Comment: @Paras - not sure how to the tackle $I_n$ yet