# Series sum $\sum 1/(n^2+(n+1)^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In an exercise, I caculate the Fourier expansion of $e^x$ over $[0,\pi]$ is
$$e^x\sim \frac{e^\pi-1}{\pi}+\frac{2(e^\pi-1)}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2nx}{4n^2+1}+\frac{4(1-e^\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n\sin 2nx}{4n^2+1}.$$
From this, it is easy to deduce 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4n^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{e^\pi+1}{e^\pi-1}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
However, I could not find the following sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2+1},$$
from which we can calculate the sum $\sum 1/(n^2+1)$.

Comment: use residue theorem ...

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386667) question.

Comment: @Mehdi Just use math analysis...

Answer (score 5):

We can approach such kind of series by considering logarithmic derivatives of Weierstrass products. For instance, from:
$$\cosh z = \prod_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{4z^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)\tag{1}$$
we get:
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\tanh\frac{\pi z}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2z}{z^2+(2n-1)^2}\tag{2},$$
so, evaluating in $z=1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2+1}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}\tanh\frac{\pi}{2}}.\tag{3}$$
With the same approach, but starting from the Weierstrass product for $\frac{\sinh z}{z}$, we can compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{1+n^2}$, too:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2+1}=\frac{-1+\pi\coth\pi}{2}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I like it! Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2} + 1}}
=\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1 + \ic}\pars{2n - 1 - \ic}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n + 1 + \ic}\pars{2n + 1 - \ic}}
={1 \over 4}\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \bracks{n + \pars{1 + \ic}/2}\bracks{n + \pars{1 - \ic}/2}}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 4}\,
{\Psi\pars{\bracks{1 + \ic}/2} - \Psi\pars{\bracks{1 - \ic}/2}\over
 \pars{1 + \ic}/2 - \pars{1 - \ic}/2}
\end{align}
where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the [Digamma Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

> Then,
>   $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2} + 1}}
> ={1 \over 4}\,\ic\bracks{\Psi\pars{1 - \ic \over 2} - \Psi\pars{1 + \ic \over 2}}
> $$

With [Euler Reflection Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula)
$\ds{\Psi\pars{1 - x} - \Psi\pars{x} = \pi\cot\pars{\pi x}}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}^{2} + 1}}
={1 \over 4}\,\ic\ \pi\cot\pars{\pi\,{1 + \ic \over 2}}
=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ic\,\pi\tan\pars{\pi\ic \over 2}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ic\,\pi\bracks{\ic\tanh\pars{\pi \over 2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 4}\,\pi\tanh\pars{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}