# How to compute $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{16}}$?

Tags: summation, power-series

How do I compute $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{16}}$ ?

Mathematica says the sum converges and it somewhat looks like the Basel problem, but so far I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the sum of $\sum 1/(k^2 - a^2)$ when $0<a<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141470/find-the-sum-of-sum-1-k2-a2-when-0a1)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386667/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to solve the usual Basel problem is given [here](http://math.cmu.edu/~bwsulliv/basel-problem.pdf#Outline0.1) (proof 1).

By some clever tricks using Euler's formula which you can check out at the link above, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1}{4+x^2}+\frac{1}{9+x^2}+\cdots&=-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{\pi\cos(-i\pi x)}{2ix\sin(-i\pi x)}
\end{align*}
and at this point we usually plug in $x=0$ to get (in a limiting way) the value $\pi^2/6$.

In your case, we can put $x=\frac i4$ to get that the sum is $\boxed{8-2\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary derivation that uses partial fractions, telescoping, and the $\arctan$ series:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1/16}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{16}{(4k+1)(4k-1)}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{16}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}\cdot\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\\
&=8\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}+8\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}\\
&=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)+4\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}-4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\\
&=-4+4(-1-\pi/4)-4\pi/4\\
&=-8-2\pi,
\end{align}
so $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-1/16} = -8-2\pi -\frac{1}{0^2-1/16}=8-2\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Residue Theorem for Infinite Series to evaluate this sum: http://www.supermath.info/InfiniteSeriesandtheResidueTheorem.pdf

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{16}}=8+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{16}}$$

$$S=8+\frac{1}{2}\left[\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{4}}\frac{-\pi \cot(\pi z)(z-\frac{1}{4})}{z^2-\frac{1}{16}}+\lim_{z\to-\frac{1}{4}}\frac{-\pi \cot(\pi z)(z+\frac{1}{4})}{z^2-\frac{1}{16}}\right]$$

$$S=8-\frac{\pi}{2}\left[2\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)-2\cot\left(-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]=2\left(4-\pi\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums are also interesting since
$$S_n=\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2-\frac{1}{16}}=-2 \left(-\psi \left(n+\frac{3}{4}\right)+\psi
   \left(n+\frac{5}{4}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)+\psi
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right)$$ whic reduce to
$$S_n=8-2\pi+2 H_{n-\frac{1}{4}}-2 H_{n+\frac{1}{4}}=8-2\pi-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2 n^2}-\frac{3}{16 n^3}+\frac{1}{32
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Use it for $n=5$
$$S_5=\frac{22338896}{14549535}\approx 1.5353684$$ while the above truncated series gives
$$S_5 \sim \frac{156371}{20000}-2 \pi\approx 1.5353647$$