# Evaluation of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-a)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering what the evaluation of the following summation is for any $|a|>0$
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-a)^2}.$$
Any help or a direction to a reference would be appreciated. There is a related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632580/evaluate-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n-a2-with-poisson-summation-for?rq=1), but I am unsure of its validity.

Comment: Why are you unsure of its validity?

Comment: @ClementC. Hi, thank you. This since the closed form was mentioned without reference. A reference if possible would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to look at this one (it seems detailed enough): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057017/75808

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you very much! That's much appreciated

Comment: a cannot be an integer!