# How $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(10n-9)^2} + \frac{1}{(10n-1)^2} \right)$ equals to $\frac{{\pi}^2}{50} \frac 1 { 1-\cos{\frac {\pi} 5} }$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(10n-9)^2} + \frac{1}{(10n-1)^2} \right) = \frac{\pi^2}{50} \frac{1}{1- \cos \frac{\pi}{5}}
$$
?

Each form of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(10n-9)^2}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(10n-1)^2}
$$

couldn't be calculated but the sum of them has a closed form

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%2810n-9%29%5E2%7D) gives a value for both sums in terms of the derivative of the digamma function.

Answer (score 3):

The $\Gamma$ function fulfills the symmetry relation
$$ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)} $$
hence by applying $\frac{d}{dz}\left(\log(\cdot)\right)$ to both sides
$$\psi(z)-\psi(1-z) =-\pi\cot(\pi z) $$
and by differentiating once again
$$ \psi'(z)+\psi'(1-z) = \frac{\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}. \tag{1}$$
Since
$$ \psi'(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+z)^2}\tag{2} $$
equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ with $z=\frac{1}{10}$ prove the claim.

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner The Digamma function, $$ \psi(z)=\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=-\gamma+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+z-1}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you; $+1$

Answer (score 1):

Using
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n-a)^2+b^2}=\frac{\pi\sinh2\pi b}{b\left(\cosh2\pi b-\cos2\pi a\right)}$$
from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386667/closed-form-for-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n-a2b2), one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{(10n-9)^2} + \frac{1}{(10n-1)^2} \right)\\
&=&\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(10n-1)^2}=\frac{1}{10^2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(n-\frac1{10})^2}\\
&=&\frac1{10}\lim_{b\to0}\frac{\pi\sinh(2\pi b)}{b\left(\cosh(2\pi b)-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{10})\right)}\\
&=&\frac{\pi^2}{50} \frac{1}{1- \cos \frac{\pi}{5}}.
\end{eqnarray}