# Want to prove certain sum representation of $\cot(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

So here is my problem,

I would like to prove an identity I found in a book which was given without a proof.

Namely
$$-i\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \operatorname{sign}(n)\cdot e^{i2\pi nx}=\cot(\pi x)$$
I thought since there is no explicit proof it would be easy to show it but I failed...

Could someone help me? Or does anybody know where I can find the proof?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505210/fourier-expansion-of-coth-and-justifying-an-identity

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Sums Oscillate**

One problem making this sum difficult is that it doesn't converge because the terms do not tend to $0$. Using the formula for the sum of a geometric series, we get
$$
\begin{align}
-i\left(\sum_{k=0}^ne^{2\pi ikx}-\sum_{k=0}^ne^{-2\pi ikx}\right)
&=-i\left(\frac{1-e^{2\pi i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{2\pi ix}}-\frac{1-e^{-2\pi i(n+1)x}}{1-e^{-2\pi ix}}\right)\\
&=-i\left(\frac{e^{-\pi ix}-e^{\pi i(2n+1)x}}{e^{-\pi ix}-e^{\pi ix}}-\frac{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi i(2n+1)x}}{e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix}}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\cos(\pi x)-\cos((2n+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\\[3pt]
&=\cot(\pi x)-\frac{\cos((2n+1)\pi x)}{\sin(\pi x)}\tag1
\end{align}
$$
So the partial sums oscillate around $\cot(\pi x)$, but they never converge (as expected).

---

**Another Method of Summation**

However, partial sums are not the only way to sum Fourier series. Partial sums correspond to the [Dirichlet Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) applied to the function. The Dirichlet Kernel is an approximation to the delta function, but it is not in $L^1$. As such, it does not approximate as well as the [Fejér Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel), which is in $L^1$ (in fact, the Fejér Kernel is non-negative). As the Dirichlet Kernel corresponds to partial summation, the Fejér Kernel corresponds to [Cesàro Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), which is like an average of partial sums.

Applying the Dirichlet Kernel corresponds to multiplying the Fourier coefficients by $[\,|k|\le n\,]$ ($\,[\dots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)). Dirichlet Kernel approximations are subject to [Gibb's Phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) around jump discontinuities (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/698775) for details on the ringing).

Applying the Fejér Kernel corresponds to multiplying the Fourier coefficients by $\left(1-\frac{|k|}n\right)[\,|k|\le n\,]$.

**Lemma:**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac kn\right)x^k=\frac{n-(n+1)x+x^{n+1}}{n(1-x)^2}\tag2
$$
**Proof:**

Since the terms with $x^k$ for $2\le k\le n$ cancel, we get
$$
\begin{align}
(1-x)^2\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)x^k
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)x^k-2\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)x^{k+1}+\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)x^{k+2}\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n(n-k)x^k}_{k\in\{0,1\}}-2\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(n-k+1)x^k}_{k\in\{1,n+1\}}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=2}^{n+2}(n-k+2)x^k}_{k\in\{n+1,n+2\}}\\
&=n-(n+1)x+x^{n+1}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
$\square$

Therefore, the Fejér Kernel applied to the sum in question can be evaluated as
$$
\begin{align}
&-i\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac kn\right)e^{2\pi ikx}-\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac kn\right)e^{-2\pi ikx}\right)\\
&=-i\left(\frac{n-(n+1)e^{2\pi ix}+e^{2\pi i(n+1)x}}{n\left(1-e^{2\pi ix}\right)^2}
-\frac{n-(n+1)e^{-2\pi ix}+e^{-2\pi i(n+1)x}}{n\left(1-e^{-2\pi ix}\right)^2}\right)\\
&=-i\left(\frac{ne^{-2\pi ix}-(n+1)+e^{2\pi inx}}{n\left(e^{-\pi ix}-e^{\pi ix}\right)^2}
-\frac{ne^{2\pi ix}-(n+1)+e^{-2\pi inx}}{n\left(e^{\pi ix}-e^{-\pi ix}\right)^2}\right)\\[3pt]
&=-i\frac{2ni\sin(2\pi x)-2i\sin(2\pi nx)}{4n\sin(\pi x)^2}\\[6pt]
&=\cot(\pi x)-\frac{\sin(2\pi nx)}{2n\sin(\pi x)^2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
which *does* converge to $\cot(\pi x)$.