# How to calculate the following: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2}=\;\;?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I calculate the following sum?

any hint please? I am beginner in such things, i have tried to make a decomposition for the denominator but no result
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+n^2}=?$$

Comment: Do you really need to calculate it, or just show that it converges?

Comment: @bkarpuz yes i need to calculate it

Comment: The analytic approach is not for beginners. But you can get a close approximation with $$\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{1+n^2} +\int_{k+1/2}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \sum_{n=0}^k \frac{1}{1+n^2} +\frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1}\left(k+\frac12\right)$$  for reasonable $k$ of say $100$ or more

Comment: There's also an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110872/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-frac11n2-frac-pi12-frac-pie