# Sum Identity without Parseval's Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, harmonic-numbers, parsevals-identity

[Show that $\int_0^\pi \log^2\left(\tan\frac{ x}{4}\right)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{4}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770654)

The following Sum Identity was derived by applying Parseval's Theorem to the integral in the question linked above.

$\displaystyle \large \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{2\mathcal{H}_{2k} - \mathcal{H}_k}{k} \right)^2 = \frac{\pi^4}{8}$

Is there a means of evaluating the sum without invoking Parseval's Theorem?