# Proof of an integration equality and an infinite series equality derived thereof

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I need hints on the proof of:

$$\int_0^\infty\dfrac{\ln(x)^2}{1+x^2}{\rm{d}x}=\dfrac{\pi^3}{8}$$

and then:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left((-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^3}\right)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}$$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Check out the value of $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^n(\ln x)^2 dx$ and the Taylor development of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ and think about change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: Thank you! this makes it clear. let me try to work it out. I think this is enough for an answer.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-alternating-zeta-series

Comment: thank you @JackD'Aurizio, I find [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762813/infinite-series-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n12m1-frac-1m-e-2?lq=1) is also related and useful! Your answer below is exactly the same thing as my post?!