# Prove $\frac{1}{1^{5}\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2})}-\frac{1}{3^{5}\cosh(\frac{3\pi}{2})}+\frac{1}{5^{5}\cosh(\frac{5\pi}{2})}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^{5}}{768}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

This is an identity from Ramanujan's letter, I am just curious. How do you prove this. My math level knowledge is still very basic so a simplified proof is preferred:

$$\frac{1}{1^{5}\cosh(\frac{\pi}{2})}-\frac{1}{3^{5}\cosh(\frac{3\pi}{2})}+\frac{1}{5^{5}\cosh(\frac{5\pi}{2})}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^{5}}{768}$$

Comment: See related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991066/72031

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3611551

Comment: Which letter? There were many of them. Could you please give the link for us wondering?

Comment: @Cheesecake: this formula as well as the one linked in my comment belong to his first letter to Hardy. That letter was the most fortunate event in the lives of both Hardy and Ramanujan. After that as they say is history.

Comment: @Cheesecake: see [this page](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2016/04/6-ramanujans-letters-from-ono-73.png) on which the formula appears. The letter contained many such pages and Hardy remarks about a thick envelope with Madras (Chennai in India now) postmark which contains these pages.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, thank you for the link! That is really a treasure! I wanted to read more after the _Mad Who Knew Infinity_ .

Comment: @Cheesecake: you can get other pages of that letter by changing the number at the end in the link I gave.

Answer (score 5):

This sum can be found using the partial fraction expansion of secant, with a similar approach to the one found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991066/72031).
Beginning with the formula
$$ \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\cosh \left(\tfrac{\pi}{2}x \right)} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (2k+1)}{(2k+1)^2+x^2} $$
valid for all real $x$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762813/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n12m1) post)
set $x=2n+1$, divide through by $(2n+1)^5$, and sum both sides to get
$$ \frac{\pi}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^5 \cosh \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k (2k+1)}{(2n+1)^5 ((2k+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)} $$
The fraction inside the double sum may be rewritten as
$$ \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k}{(2n+1)^5(2k+1)} - \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k}{(2n+1)^3(2k+1)^3}+\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^k}{(2n+1)(2k+1)^5}-\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^k(2n+1)}{(2k+1)^5((2n+1)^2+(2k+1)^2)} $$
Notice that the rightmost fraction is the same as the one we started with if we switch the dummy variables. Therefore we have
$$ \hspace{-10cm} 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k (2k+1)}{(2n+1)^5 ((2k+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)} $$
$$ \hspace{5cm} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k}{(2n+1)^5(2k+1)} - \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k}{(2n+1)^3(2k+1)^3}+\frac{(-1)^n(-1)^k}{(2n+1)(2k+1)^5} \right) $$
Using the Dirichlet beta function values
$$ \beta(1) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$ \beta(3) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} = \frac{\pi^3}{32} $$
$$ \beta(5) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^5} = \frac{5\pi^5}{1536} $$
we find that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (-1)^k (2k+1)}{(2n+1)^5 ((2k+1)^2+(2n+1)^2)} = \beta(1)\beta(5)-\frac{1}{2}\beta^2(3) = \frac{\pi^6}{3072} $$ and so $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^5 \cosh \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right)} = \frac{\pi^5}{768} $$

Comment: Nice and very simple proof. Ramanujan would have loved it. +1

Comment: Thanks! This method generalizes to give the formula $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n sech \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right)}{(2n+1)^{4m+1}} = \frac{4}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} (-1)^k \beta(4m-2k+1) \beta(2k+1) + \frac{(-1)^m 2}{\pi} \beta^2(2m+1) $$ for any positive integer $m$. It can also be used with the other three trig partial fractions to gives formulas for $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^{4m+3}} $, $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\tanh \left(\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2} \right)}{n^{4m+3}} $, and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n csch(\pi n)}{n^{4m+3}} $.

Comment: I think you should post such sums here as question and also provide an answer. This may lead to other interesting approaches by other people.