# Summation $S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}\right)\right)$$

Let,
$$f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2k+1}\ln\left(2k+a\right)\right)$$
then S can be represented as follows (after expanding everything):
$$S=4f(1)-2f(-1)-2f(3)$$

Although I am not sure, but $f(1)$ seems to have a closed form as follows:
$$-\frac{1}{4}\gamma_{1}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4}\gamma_1\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)+\ln\left(2\right)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\right)$$
where, $\gamma_n$ is the $n$th Stieltjes Constant.

I did get the answer for $f(1)$ without the Stieltjes Consants from one of my friends as follows:
$$-\frac{\pi}{4}\left(\gamma+2\ln2+3\ln\left(\pi\right)-4\ln\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]\right)$$
He mentioned it as "Dirichlet Beta Derivative Evaluated at 1".

As a side note, this would imply:
$$\gamma_1\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)-\gamma_1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=-\pi \gamma-4\pi\ln2-3\pi\ln\left(\pi\right)+4\pi\ln\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]+8\ln\left(2\right)$$

I have no idea about $f(-1)$ and $f(3)$.

Also, I have no reason to believe a Closed Form Exists.

Edit:
Using another approach as follows:

Using Series Expansion for $\ln(1-x)$ and rearranging the Summation:
$$S=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{1+2r}}{r}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)^{1+2r}}$$

And it seems that:
[Infinite Series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^{2m+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762813/infinite-series-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n12m1)
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)^{1+2r}}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}E_{2r}\pi^{2r+1}}{2^{2r+2}\left(2r\right)!}$$
where, $E_{2r}$ are the Euler Numbers.

$$S=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\alpha}\frac{2^{1+2r}}{r}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r}E_{2r}\pi^{2r+1}}{2^{2r+2}\left(2r\right)!}-1\right)$$
Though this probably made it tougher.

Comment: The sum can be presented in the for of integral
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}\right)\right)=-8\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-\arctan(e^{-x})}x\sinh^2x\,dx$$
I don't think that a closed form is feasible...

Comment: @Svyatoslav Interesting! How did you come up with that?

Answer (score 4):

*Too long for a comment*

Using the Frullani's integral $\displaystyle\ln n=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-e^{-nt}}tdt$

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k+\frac{1}{2}}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k+\frac12}\ln\frac{(k-\frac12)(k+\frac32)}{(k+\frac12)^2}$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{2e^{-\frac t2}-e^{-\frac{3t}2}-e^{\frac t2}}t\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}e^{-kt}}{k+\frac12}\right)dt$$
Now, using
$$2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k+1}e^{-kt}=2i\sum_{k=1}^\infty (i)^{2k+1}\frac{e^{-(2k+1)\frac t2}e^\frac t2}{2k+1}=2+ie^\frac t2\ln\frac{1+ie^{-\frac t2}}{1-ie^{-\frac t2}}$$
$$=2-2e^\frac t2\Im\ln(1+ie^{-\frac t2})=2-2e^\frac t2\Im\ln\left(\sqrt{1+e^{-t}}e^{i\arctan e^{-\frac t2}}\right)=2-2e^\frac t2\arctan e^{-\frac t2}$$
Therefore, the sum can be presented as an integral in the form
$$S=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^\frac t2\arctan e^{-\frac t2}}t\left(2e^{-\frac t2}-e^{-\frac{3t}2}-e^\frac t2\right)dt$$
$$=-8\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-\arctan(e^{-t})}t\sinh^2t\,dt$$

Comment: Alternate form of 
$$S=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u-\arctan\left(u\right)}{\ln\left(u\right)u}\left(u-\frac{1}{u}\right)^{2}du$$

Comment: I tried something for the integral you wrote but I am stuck. Any idea ? Thanks and cheers :-)  and (+1) for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Svyatoslav's solution
$$S=-8\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t}-\arctan(e^{-t})}t\,\sinh^2(t)\,dt$$

Using
$$\sinh^2(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{2 n-1}}{(2 n)!}\, t^{2 n}$$
$$J_n=\int_0^\infty t^{2 n-1} \left(e^{-t}-\tan ^{-1}\left(e^{-t}\right)\right)\,dt$$

$$J_n=\frac{1}{2} (2-i \text{Li}_{2 n+1}(-i)+i \text{Li}_{2 n+1}(i))\, \Gamma (2 n)$$

$$S=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {4^n}n (2-i \text{Li}_{2 n+1}(-i)+i \text{Li}_{2 n+1}(i)) $$

But, using Dirichlet beta and eta functions
$$i (\text{Li}_{2 n+1}(i)-\text{Li}_{2 n+1}(-i))=$$ $$2^{-(4 n+1)} \left(\zeta \left(2 n+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(2
   n+1,\frac{1}{4}\right)\right)$$

$$\color{blue}{S=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4^{2 n+1}+\zeta \left(2 n+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta \left(2
   n+1,\frac{1}{4}\right)}{4^{2 n+1}\, n }}$$

which converges very fast (the summand being more or less $e^{-(n+1)}$)

*Now, I am stuck.*

**Edit**

May be shorter but for the same result
$$f(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{2k+1}\log\left(2k+a\right)$$
$$f'(a)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2 k+1)(2k+a)}=\frac{2 \Phi \left(-1,1,\frac{a+2}{2}\right)-(4-\pi)}{4 (a-1)}$$

Comment: In:
$$S=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{1+2r}}{r}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)^{1+2r}}$$
Wolfram did Evaluate the Second Sum as:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k+1\right)^{1+2r}}=-2^{-4r-2}\left(\zeta\left(2r+1,\frac{3}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(2r+1,\frac{5}{4}\right)\right)$$